# Comedy spy movie (probably with Leslie Nielsen)

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I remember 3 scenes from a movie which is in the style of Leslie Nielsen's spy-agent comedies.

- Beginning of the movie - He thinks someone is watching him while he walks down the street. He stops, (probably leans down to fix his shoelaces) and then uses the gadget - a small nail-mirror inside of his thumb.
- He is asking someone to get on the roof of the building where the conversation will be more secure. 4 helicopters then take off and produce noise (and wind) and as it proves unpractical and deadly - he/or someone else suggests something different.
- They get into some hi-tech chamber (almost like small submarine) which mutes all voices and sounds - but - instead of voice, they can see the words and letters they say. And in comedy style - one of them eats some of those letters.

Does anyone remember the title of this movie? It is from the 80-90s, maybe 2000's.

Comment: Leslie Nielsen's spy spoof is Spy Hard., but the scenes don't seem to fit.

Comment: I agree. I looked over at his filmography and didnt find anything exept the similarity of comedy, gadgets and spy-agent story. Perhaps it was some simmilar looking actor. Cant be 100% sure because I saw that movie at least some 10 years ago...

Comment: May I ask why you edited the question to put back the spelling and grammar errors that were corrected?

Comment: I added some text for better recognition of scenes. I did nothing to corrected text. Didnt notice any changes exept someone removing one of my tags. I just needed to know title of the movie and fast so I didnt spent much time looking around site and getting familiar with its notifications and so on. English isnt my native language. Sorry. But thanks for correction. Bye! ;)

Comment: And don't call me Shirley.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is [Get Smart, Again!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097423/)(1989).  Don Adams was the agent.  #2 and #3 sound like variations on the running joke of the "cone of silence".  This movie featured the variation called "hover cover", where several helicopters hovered nearby to drown out the sound.  The third one is the classic "cone of silence", but with a kind of subtitle feature.

Comment: Yes! YES! That is it! Thank you! :)

www.youtube.com/watch?v=gV-NkDZz7fQ

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark.